# replace any strings with nan in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and the dataframe-concept. Because of the format of my data (excel-sheets, first row is the name of my data, the second row is the unit) it's a little tricky to handle it in a data frame.
The task is to calculate new data from existing columns, e.g. `df.['c'] = df['a']**2 + df.['b']`
I get: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

This did work, but is pain to my hands and eyes:

```
df.['c'] = df['a']
df.['c'] = df['a'].tail(len(df.['a']-1))**2 + df.['b'].tail(len(df.['b'])-1)
df.loc[0,'c'] = 'unit for c'
```

Is there any way to do this quicker or  with less typing? 
Thanks already
schamonn

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Hi schamonn, can you show how you read in your excel data and a small example of your dataframe? Not an image please, but in code. This really helps solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the error mentioned first in this post.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

What this error is staying that you are trying to take and string to a power, we can replicate this error using the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','2','3'],'b':[4,5,6]})

df['a']**2
```

Output last line of stack trace:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

A simple resolution to this if all your a column are numeric representations, then use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['a'])**2
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    4
2    9
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

#### Got non-numeric strings also in column a?

Use `errors = 'coerce'` as a parameter to `pd.to_numeric`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','1','2','3'],'b':[4,5,6,7]})
```

Use:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce')**2
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    4.0
3    9.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi, this helps. But additionally I have the problem, that I can't do pd.to_numeric to the string in the first row of each column.

Comment: Try `pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce')**2` to force conversion of those that can convert and use NaN for values that can't convert.

Comment: @schamonn See update.   You can use `fillna` to replace that NaN with zero of `bfill` ect...

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I needed! Thx so much

Answer (score 0):

this is how I read in the data

```
Data = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name = 'Messung')
In [154]: Data
Out[154]: 
   T1   T2 Messung                Datum
0  °C   °C       -                    -
1  12  100       1  2018-12-06 00:00:00
2  15  200       2  2018-12-06 00:00:00
3  20  120       3  2018-12-06 00:00:00
4  10  160       4  2018-12-06 00:00:00
5  12  160       5  2018-12-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: It is recommended you modify the question and add this information to the question.